# Como passar para o próximo input usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Montei um formulário em `HTML` mas eu queria que quando um usuário apertasse a tecla ENTER ele fosse para o próximo campo.

Exemplo, o primeiro campo tem que preencher com o nome, quando a pessoa apertasse ENTER ela iria para a opção de baixo (usuário) e assim sucessivamente.

```html
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Nome:
      <span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" required="required" type="text">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Usuário:
     <span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Confirmar usuário:
     <span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="email" id="email2" name="confirm_email" data-validate-linked="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label for="password" class="control-label col-md-3">Senha:</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" data-validate-length="6,8" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label for="password2" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Confirmar senha:</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input id="password2" type="password" name="password2" data-validate-linked="password" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required">
   </div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que seria isso meu querido. Abraços!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('#name').focus();
    
    $(document).find('input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {//Enter key pressed
            e.preventDefault();
            
            $(this).closest('.item')
            .next().first()
            .find('input')
            .focus();

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Nome:
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name"
                          required="required" type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Usuário:
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Confirmar usuário:
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="email" id="email2" name="confirm_email" data-validate-linked="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="item form-group">
                      <label for="password" class="control-label col-md-3">Senha:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" data-validate-length="6,8" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                      <label for="password2" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Confirmar senha:</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input id="password2" type="password" name="password2" data-validate-linked="password" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                          required="required">
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar este código, usando apenas JavaScript sem bibliotecas adicionais.

No HTML, você adiciona o atributo `tabindex`:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" tabindex="3">
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input,select");
for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
      if (e.which == 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var nextInput = document.querySelectorAll('[tabIndex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]');
         if (nextInput.length === 0) {
            nextInput = document.querySelectorAll('[tabIndex="1"]');
         }
         nextInput[0].focus();
      }
   })
}
```

Ao pressionar ENTER o *foco* irá para o próximo *tabindex*
Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558555/194717

Answer (score 1):

Em JavaScript puro sem alterações no HTML, você pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("input.form-control");
for (var x=0; x<els.length; x++) {
   els[x].addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
      var k = e.which || e.keyCode;
      if(k == 13){
         e.preventDefault();
         var p = this.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.querySelector("input.form-control");
         if(p) p.focus();
      }
   });
}
```

```html
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Nome:
      <span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" required="required" type="text">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Usuário:
     <span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Confirmar usuário:
     <span class="required">*</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="email" id="email2" name="confirm_email" data-validate-linked="email" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label for="password" class="control-label col-md-3">Senha:</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password" data-validate-length="6,8" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group">
   <label for="password2" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Confirmar senha:</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input id="password2" type="password" name="password2" data-validate-linked="password" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required">
   </div>
</div>
```